# Reduction code for CUDA GPU in finite element assembly

Tags: assembly, cuda, element

We have an unstructured tetrahedral mesh file containing following format:

```
element-ID  nod1 nod2 nod3 nod4

1            452  3434 322 9000

2           2322   837 6673 2323

.
.
.

300000
```

So a C function

```
calc()
{

   for (int i=1;i<=no-of-elements;i++)
   {
      n1=nod1[i];
      n2=nod2[i];
      n3=nod3[i];
      n4=nod4[i];

      ax[n1] += some code;

      ax[n2] += some code;

      ax[n3] += some code;

      ax[n4] += some code;

   }

}
```

How to implement the above code in CUDA on Tesla in a race-free condition manner or any other alternative way on CUDA?

Comment: The question as it stands is somewhat unclear, but I think I know what you're hinting at. Are you asking how to structure your computation of the nodal contributions without resorting to things like atomics?

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the question - probably I don't know some of the terminology. What is a "tetrahedral mesh file"? What is "3 lakh"? Right now I see some quadruples which are used as indexes to an array (leading to really bad memory access patterns!). Do we have any assumptions regarding the indices?

Comment: @CygnusX1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh , but yes, that was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use graph coloring to partition the mesh into subdomains. Each colour has the property that the elements in it can be assembled in parallel without memory races. Using this approach you only require as many passes through the mesh as there are colors in order to complete assembly.

There is a lot of literature available on parallel finite element assembly, and a number of very good graph partitioning codes available (for example [Metis](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/views/metis)). Google scholar is probably the best place to start on learning about the technique.

Comment: +1 I agree. In our case with 2D (triangle) elements we have had good results using a gather approach in which nodal contributions by each element are simply computed and stored in a first kernel and subsequently gathered by a second kernel which has a thread per node. I can't vouch for the OP's case though, but it might be worth to have a poke at it.

Comment: @talonmies     thanks for the answer                               

we partitioned the mesh into parts
each part contains a partition with unique nodes n1,n2,n3,n4


we pass the  partition size to kernel


ie; if partition size is 2048
then on Tesla with 512 threads limit


we do
<pre><code>
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....);
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....);
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....);
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....);</pre></code>

the problem is we cannot use more than 1 block at a time.
example:calc<<<2,512>>>(d_ax,....); //does not work
calc<<<2,512>>>(d_ax,....); //does not work

Comment: @Krakesh: It is impossible to comment on why *your* implementation doesn't work without seeing it. If you can formulate your problem as a *concise* programming question, then ask it as a new question. Otherwise, how can you possibly expect any help just based on your comment?

Comment: @talonmies I posted another question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284773/cuda-kernel-for-finite-element-assembly)