# CUDA kernel for Finite Element Assembly

Tags: assembly, cuda, element

We have an unstructured tetrahedral mesh file containing following format:

```
element-ID  nod1 nod2 nod3 nod4


    1            452  3434  322 9000

    2            2322   837 6673 2323

    .
    .
    .

300000
```

We partitioned the above mesh for partition size of 2048 each.
For each partition size of 2048 contains unique nod1 nod2 nod3 nod4 values, we pass 1 block and 512  threads at different start index.

In a cuda file, we have

```
__global__ void calc(double d_ax,int *nod1,int *node2,int *nod3,int *nod4,int   start,int size)
{
    int n1,n2,n3,n4;     
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + start;


    if ( i < size )
    {

        n1=nod1[i];
        n2=nod2[i];
        n3=nod3[i];
        n4=nod4[i];

        ax[n1] += some code;
        ax[n2] += some code;
        ax[n3] += some code;
        ax[n4] += some code;
    }
}
```

We call the kernel as

```
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....,0,512);
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....,512,512);
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....,1024,512); 
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....1536,512);
```

the above code works well but the problem is we get *different results* using more than one block at a time. For example:

```
calc<<<2,512>>>(d_ax,....,0,1024); 
calc<<<2,512>>>(d_ax,....,1024,1024);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you edit the question to explain *why* can't you use more that one block? And while you are at it could you fix *all* the code in your question - it is so incomplete and full of errors that you may as well not have posted it, it is no help to anyone trying to answer your question

Comment: I have voted to have this question closed as too localized. It looks like your problem is due to basic programming mistakes and/or a complete lack of understanding about even the basics of CUDA. That sort of question doesn't belong on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you expect anyone to tell you what might be wrong when the code you have posted is incomplete and uncompilable, but *if* in your single block case you really are calling the kernel as you have posted, this is what should happen:

```
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....,0,512);    // process first 512 elements
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....,512,512);  // start >= 512, size == 512, does nothing
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....,1024,512); // start >= 1024, size == 512, does nothing
calc<<<1,512>>>(d_ax,....1536,512);  // start >= 1536, size == 512, does nothing
```

So irrespective of whether your code might be broken when run using multiple blocks, your results for the single block case are probably wrong, and the whole point of your question is probably irrelevant as a result.

If you want a better answer, edit your question so it contains a complete description of the problem and concise, complete code that could actually be compiled. Otherwise this is about as much as anybody could guess from the information you have provided.

Comment: size is the number of elements to process

Comment: @Krakesh: I understand that, but according to the code you posted, you are only performing the summation calculations when `blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + start < size` which can never be true for anything other than the first block when you call it with `size=512`

Answer (score 0):

> For each partition size of 2048 contains unique nod1 nod2 nod3 nod4
>   values

but in two partition sets the same node index can appear?
If in two different blocks you have

Block 1:
`ax[1234]=do something`

Block 2:
`ax[1234]=do something else`

it smells as a race condition. You never know which one of the two blocks will be faster to write....